# How do you send XLM from Coinbase to Nano Ledger X?

Tags: ledger

Each time I try to send XLM from coinbase to ledger X, it's telling me 'send failed'. The address is correct, cut and pasted from the account and verified by Nano X and Stellar account. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. I just put a random memo in memo ID and it worked. The memo id not  needed for transfer to a personal wallet but CB requires you to have one none the less.